# grep/perl regex for finding a header and a matching line

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Let's say I have a file, called courses.txt with contents like below.
the file has sections(course providers and my email used) followed by various courses. example : edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)  and then the various course names, each preceded by the serial number.

```
udemy (anjan.bar@gmail.com)  
"=========================="-  
1) foo bar
2) java programming language
3) redis stephen grider
4) javascript
5) react with typescript
6) kotlin
7) Etherium and Solidity : the Complete Developer's Guide
8) reactive programming with spring  


coursera (anjan.foo@gmail.com)  
"==========================-"  
1) python
2) typescript
3) java concurrency
4) C#

edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)  
"==========================-"  
1) excel
2) scala
3) risk management
4) stock
5) oracle
6) mysql  
7) java  
==========================-
```

Question : I want to grep for a course, say "java". I want a match which shows me the particular line(s) of the match(example : "java") and the corresponding section name(say, "edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)"  ).

if I want to search for "java" what "regex" will give me following matches (I use grep/perl on windows):

```
  <br>
udemy (anjan.bar@gmail.com)    
2) java programming language  

coursera (anjan.foo@gmail.com)  
3) java concurrency

edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)    
7) java
```

I tried lookbehind/lookahead but couldn't figure out how to print the course provider name with email and the course name.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you process in paragraphs (chunks of text separated by blank lines) then in each paragraph it is fairly straightforward to match the needed pattern -- the header (followed by a line with `=`'s) and a line with `java` in it

```
perl -00 -wnE'say "$1\n$2" 
    if /(.+?) \n "=+.+? \n .+? \n ([^\n]+\sjava\s[^\n]+)/sx' file
```

(Tested on Linux; read on for Windows. Broken into lines for easier reading. See below for explanation of the pattern.)

At the end of the line with `=`s I use `.+?` instead of the specific characters that follow `=`s in your input because your sample input isn't consistent; it has both `-"` and `"-`, in different paragraphs.  Adjust as suitable.

Since this is on Windows, where you may have to use `"` delimiters for the one-liner (I don't know what shell you use), you may need to replace the literal `"` inside the pattern with `\x22` (hex for `"`), or your other favorite sequence.

Hopefully good for Windows (can't test on Windows right now)

```
perl -00 -wnE "say qq($1\n$2) 
    if /(.+?)\n \x22=+.+? \n .+? \n ([^\n]+\sjava\s[^\n]+) /sx
" file
```

The [-00 switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D) makes it read in paragraphs. With the `/x` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) spaces inside the pattern are ignored so we can use them to space things out for readability.  With the `/s` modifier the `.` matches a newline as well. This is important for the middle `.+?` to matche multiple lines, up to the one with `java` (surrounded by spaces).<sup>†</sup>

If you don't mind having a script instead of a one-liner, what I recommend, then, for example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

local $/ = "\n\n";

while (<>) { 
    say "$1\n$2" 
        if /(.+?) \n "=+.+? \n .+? \n ([^\n]+ \sjava\s [^\n]+)/sx;
}
```

The [<> operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads files given on the command line, line by line, but the notion of a "line" is earlier set to a paragraph with `local $/ = "\n\n"`.  That [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29) is there in case this is a part of a larger program where you don't want to change the [$/ variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/) for the whole program!

---

<sup>†</sup>  Or, instead of using `/s` that makes `.` match newlines, use a pattern for multiple lines

```
perl -00 -wnE'say "$1\n$2" 
    if /(.+) \n "=+.+ \n (?:.+\n)* (.+\sjava\s.+)/x' file
```

Or, if you need `"..."` on Windows, like

```
perl -00 -wnE "say qq($1\n$2) 
    if /(.+) \n \x22=+.+ \n (?:.+\n)* (.+\sjava\s.+)/x' file
```

(Again, I can't test on Windows right now.)

Note that now we don't have to make all those `.+` non-greedy with the added `?` (`.+?`) like in the patterns with `/s` above -- now that `.+` stops at a newline, just as needed here.

Or, use the `/s` modifier dynamically, via [extended patterns](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%5Ealupimnsx))

```
perl -00 -wnE "say "$1\n$2" 
    if /(.+) \n \x22=+.+ \n (?s).+?(?-s) (.+\sjava\s.+)/x
" file
```

Here `(?s)` "turns on" the `/s` modifier, which would be in effect until the end of the enclosing group (the rest of the pattern in this case), but `(?-s)` turns it off.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you a complete solution, but you can start with this:

```
grep -iE "java|@" filename.txt
```

Some explanation:

- the `-i` makes it case insensitive
- the `-E` uses extended regular expressions
- the `|` is an example of those extended regular expressions and it means "OR": show the lines which contain 'java' OR '@' (the latter being all the email adresses)

As a result, you get a file with all the e-mail addresses, and all the 'java' courses, together with a catch: if a line with an e-mail address is followed by another line with an e-mail address, then there's no 'java' course for that address. Hence, you can now use Perl and remove the e-mail addresses where the next line also is an e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the input data we can conclude that section starts with a line which includes email address.

Data for the section starts with serial number.

Based on this information we can build a hash `%sections` with line which includes email as a *key*, and all lines starting with serial number can be stored in an *array* under the key.

Once the hash is build the code goes through all sections and looks for lines which include search term, if the term found the output *section* with matching *line*.

Note: to work on real file replace `<DATA>` with `<>` then run as `./script.pl filename.dat`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($lookfor, %sections, $key);

$lookfor = shift || die "Provide search term";

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    $key = $_ if /@/;
    push @{$sections{$key}}, $_ if /^\d\) /;
}

for my $section (keys %sections ) {
    for( @{$sections{$section}} ) {
        say "$section\n"
          . '-' x 30
          . "\n$_\n" if /\b$lookfor\b/i;
    }
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
udemy (anjan.bar@gmail.com)  
"=========================="-  
1) foo bar
2) java programming language
3) redis stephen grider
4) javascript
5) react with typescript
6) kotlin
7) Etherium and Solidity : the Complete Developer's Guide
8) reactive programming with spring  


coursera (anjan.foo@gmail.com)  
"==========================-"  
1) python
2) typescript
3) java concurrency
4) C#

edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)  
"==========================-"  
1) excel
2) scala
3) risk management
4) stock
5) oracle
6) mysql  
7) java  
==========================-    
<br>
```

Output

```
edX (anjan.fizz@gmail.com)
------------------------------
7) java

coursera (anjan.foo@gmail.com)
------------------------------
3) java concurrency

udemy (anjan.bar@gmail.com)
------------------------------
2) java programming language
```